# Regex - Replace numbers with other characters + themselves

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a document with several 3-digit numbers, example:

```
blablabla, 305, blabla 401
503 bla bla 708
```

I need to make them bold, using `*number*` in a text editor. Is it possible, in Notepad++, to find & replace these numbers and insert the * symbol before and after them? I tried to find in Notepad++ using regex option check for `\d{3}`, but I don't know how can I replace `\d{3}` for something like `*\d{3}*`

Comment: Why use parentheses? Use `\d{3}` as rgex and replace with `*$0*`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks it worked! answer the post question so I can mark it as resolved :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `\d{3}` in the *Find What* field and `*$0*` in the *Replace With* field.

The `$0` backreference inserts the whole match value.

Note that to only match 3 digit sequences as whole words, you may use `\b\d{3}\b` where `\b` stands for a word boundary.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well if the case is only 3-digit numbers then you have to make sure that it doesn't matches numbers like `123` in `1234`. For that you have to implement a lookahead for non-digits.

**Regex:** `\d{3}(?=\D)` and replacement will be `*$0*`

Note that the last number `3456` is not matched.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think of that you're right, fortunately my file only had 3-digits, I'll take note of that :)

Comment: @ryoishikawa74: My answer also contains a better fix for that scenario - word boundaries: `\b\d{3}\b`. Unless you have glued digits and letters. Then you need `(?<!\d)\d{3}(?!\d)`